# How to distinguish two responses that have the same status code but different response body?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, http

I have an application where users can take part of puzzle solving events. I have an API endpoint `/events/{id}` that is used to get data associated to a certain event.
Based on whether the event has ended, the response will differ:

1. If the event has ended, the endpoint will return event name, participants, scores etc. with status code 200
2. If the event has not ended, the endpoint will return event name, start time, end time, puzzles etc. with status code 200.

On the client-side, what is the best way to distinguish these two responses from each other to decide which page to display, results page or event page? Is this a good way to accomplish my goal?
Some might answer that I should already know on the client-side whether the event has ended and then query for data accordingly. But what if user uses the address bar to navigate to an event? Then I will have no data to know, whether it truly has ended. I wouldn't like to first make an API call to know that it has (not) ended and then make another one for results/puzzles.

Comment: pass a boolean isFinished and return it inside of response object. If your response object is already defined, create a wrapper that has the previous response dto and a boolean flag.

Comment: @JAsgarov sorry for the late response. It's not an ideal solution, but as I cannot think of a better one myself, I will go with it. If you write it as an answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass a boolean isFinished and return it inside of response object. If your response object is already defined, create a wrapper that has the previous response dto and a boolean flag.

Also we did use a solution like this in one of our projects at work for a big company so I would say it is somewhat industry accepted way of doing it.

Comment: I've created the wrapper class that has two fields - `isFinished` and `eventData`. So data type of `eventData` should be a class that extends the wrapper class. I tried to mark the field data type as `Class<? extends EventWrapper>`, but when I am creating a new instance of the wrapper and passing a class `Event` (that extends `EventWrapper`) to its constructor, I get an error `Required type: Class<? extends EventWrapper>; Provided: Event`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't tell u without seeing the class definitions but u dnt have to use generics (that is actually not necessarily applicable here). Simple new Dto that has eventData and boolean, like so `class WrapperDTO { private EventData eventData; private boolean isFinished; //constructor, getters, setters }`

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, the content of `eventData` as a response object can differ, meaning I cannot set the type to a certain fixed one. Depending whether the event has ended, the type can be something like `EventEndedData` or `EventHasNotEndedData`. I will probably ask a new question for this and then I'll update this comment to include a link to it.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I didn't have to create a new instance of the wrapper class, but rather of the `Event` class and as it extends the wrapper class, I can access the `isFinished` field, which now is the only field in the wrapper class. I can now access all fields from this instance that are in the wrapper and event class.